# Why do we modify prepositions when using nominalisation?

Tags: nominalization

When converting from Verbalstil to Nominalstil, some instructions I found were to convert to change the prepositions:

> nachdem->nach
>
> seitdem->seit
>
> als->bei
>
> bis->bis zu
>
> bevor->vor

Could someone explain why we do this? I am trying to gain more intuition for how Nominalstil works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nachdem, seitdem, als, bis, bevor* aren't prepositions to begin with. They are conjunctions. Conjuctions join two clauses, hence the name *con* —“with”— and *junction* —well, you know what that one means—.

That clause introduced by *nachdem* et al. is a so called *adverbial clause*. So it's an adverbial inside the outer clause. But there's another kind of adverbials as well. It's those noun phrases that are introduced by a preposition (and that aren't a prepositional object).

For many kinds of adverbial clauses, there's an equivalent adverbial noun phrase and this is what *Verbalstil* vs *Nominalstil* is all about. You have to drill the pairs of conjunction and preposition that belong together. And you have to know which nouns match a certain verb.

For both there's no simple recipe. For example:

> Er geht spazieren, **nachdem er gegessen hat.**
>
> Er geht **nach dem Essen** spazieren.

> Sie spielt Flöte, **seit(dem) sie ein Kind ist.**
>
> Sie spielt **seit ihrer Kindheit** Flöte.

> Der Fußgänger geht los, **als es grün wird.**
>
> Der Fußgänger geht **bei grün** los.

> Spielt gefälligst draußen, **bis die Sonne untergeht!**
>
> Spielt gefälligst **bis zum Sonnenuntergang** draußen!

> Denkt daran, dass ihr ins Haus kommt, **bevor die Sonne untergeht!**
>
> Denkt daran, **vor dem Sonnenuntergang** ins Haus zu kommen!

In the last example I also exchanged the *dass* led object clause for an infinitive clause, as eliminating conjugated verbs all over the place is a common practice in *Nominalstil*.

Comment: how does noun phrase differ from prepositional object

Comment: So we map an adverbial phrase into an adverbial noun clause

Comment: Adverbials differ from prepositional objects. Both are noun phrases. An adverbial gives *additional* information about the situation while a prepositional object is a sort of object required by a certain *verb phrase*. For example in the sentence *Ein Wegweiser zeigt auf den Brunnen.* that part *auf den Brunnen* is a directional adverbial while in the sentence *Er wartet auf den Bus.* that part *auf den Bus* is a prepositional object required by the verb phrase *warten auf*.

Comment: You can tell the two apart by recognizing that the usual meaning of the preposition does not apply: it's a prepositional object then. It only makes sense together with the verb.

Comment: No, you map an adverbial clause to an adverbial noun phrase.